# Problems installing signal processing and machine learning toolbox Bob

Tags: python, python-bob

I'm trying to install the package from: https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad.

I had to edit the spec-file.txt to update the missing links with the earliest version available from each package and also modified the buildout file to connect via http instead of ssh. I working with conda + mamba in Ubuntu 20.04 and bob.extension is installed, however I can't get past this point when running `buildout`. Any tips on how to fix this? Thank you.

Here is the prompt I get with `buildout`:

```
    mr.developer: Queued 'bob.db.hqwmca' for checkout.
mr.developer: Queued 'bob.io.stream' for checkout.
mr.developer: Queued 'bob.ip.stereo' for checkout.
mr.developer: Skipped checkout of existing package 'bob.db.hqwmca'.
mr.developer: Skipped checkout of existing package 'bob.io.stream'.
mr.developer: Skipped checkout of existing package 'bob.ip.stereo'.
Develop: '/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/src/bob.io.stream'
bob.buildout.tools: taking requirement `setuptools' (45.2.0) from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
bob.buildout.tools: taking requirement `numpy' (1.22.1) from `/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/eggs/numpy-1.22.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg'
bob.buildout.tools: taking requirement `scipy' (1.7.3) from `/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/eggs/scipy-1.7.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg'
bob.buildout.tools: Installing `bob.io.base' for package `/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/src/bob.io.stream'...
Getting distribution for 'bob.io.base'.
WARNING: The easy_install command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-taijyg5a/bob.io.base-4.0.0/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bob.extension'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2372, in main
    setup(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 450, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 693, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 738, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 923, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1191, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1177, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-taijyg5a/bob.io.base-4.0.0/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bob.extension'
An error occurred when trying to install /tmp/tmpo3qzby_8get_dist/bob.io.base-4.0.0.zip. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing.
  Processing develop directory '/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/src/bob.io.stream'.
  Getting distribution for 'bob.io.base'.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 2174, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 679, in install
    installed_develop_eggs = self._develop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 922, in _develop
    zc.buildout.easy_install.develop(setup, dest)
  File "/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/eggs/bob.buildout-2.3.0-py3.8.egg/bob/buildout/extension.py", line 170, in develop
    tools.satisfy_requirements(self.buildout, directory, working_set)
  File "/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/eggs/bob.buildout-2.3.0-py3.8.egg/bob/buildout/tools.py", line 231, in satisfy_requirements
    working_set = install_package(buildout, req, working_set)
  File "/home/angela/Descargas/bob.paper.ijcb2021_vision_transformer_pad/eggs/bob.buildout-2.3.0-py3.8.egg/bob/buildout/tools.py", line 200, in install_package
    new_ws = zc.buildout.easy_install.install(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 957, in install
    return installer.install(specs, working_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 682, in install
    for dist in self._get_dist(requirement, ws):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 574, in _get_dist
    dists = [_move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile(dist, self._dest)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 1745, in _move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile
    [tmp_loc] = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dest, '*'))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)
```

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple python versions installed? Because there is both `/usr/lib/python3` and `/usr/lib/python3.8` in the traceback.

Comment: Yes, how could I fix that? This is what `whereis python` prompts: `python: /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python3.6-config /usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.6m /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/pyth`

Comment: bob beta packages get deleted regularly. so the conda env is broken. I have contacted the author to fix the installation instructions in the repo so you can install this package.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems you have a lot of different Python versions installed; 2.7, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8.

Normally, having multiple versions of Python 3 installed is not a problem in and of itself. But it can lead to mistakes.
Especially since there *usually* is a `python3` link that can only point to *one version*.

So what I suspect that happened is that you installed `bob.extensions` for a different Python version then the one you are using for `bob.paper`.
*Or* you installed it in a different virtual environment (if you are using those)!

My recommendation is to check if you *really* need all the different versions. If not, note down which packages you have installed for the different Python version and decide which ones you need.
Then *delete* all Python versions except 3.8, and make sure that there is a link `python3` pointing to `python3.8`.
Then install all the prequisites and `bob.extensions` and `bob.paper` on that.

I've never used conda on a non-windows machine, and normally I would advise to stick with `python` from python.org, or whatever your distribution has packages for.